# scrolling within an overflow:visible; div, when the child contents exceed the parent height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar navigation menu with children and sub-children which appear on hover. Here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/s096zfpd/

This is obviously heavily simplified just to give an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. My issue is that sometimes the list within `<nav>` exceeds the height of `<nav>`. In this case, I want to be able to scroll within `<nav>`, but doing so would compromise the `overflow-x:visible` property which I need to display `.sub-nav`, since CSS simply doesn't allow the simultaneous use of `overflow-x:visible` and `overflow-y:scroll`.

I'm thinking that maybe a js solution could work well here. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle and shared link.

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/s096zfpd/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visible for either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` and something other than visible for the other. The visible value is interpreted as auto It means that we can not apply visible and hidden to same DOM element, so ideal solution would be

- To create a wrapper and then apply `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to two different DOM elements. Sharing the js fiddle solution to your problem

  https://jsfiddle.net/e2edvupc/

Comment: have you intentionally used `overflow-x` on both elements? I'm not sure how this is a solution; I need the entire list to scroll vertically whilst still having `.sub-nav` visible on hover. There is no overflowing content on `.sub-nav`, so having any `overflow` property on that element is pointless.

Can you provide an updated jsfiddle?

Comment: Please Check the jsfiddle link that i shared and if it helps your problems then please mark my answer as complete. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but with this idea you can't click any of the links within `.sub-nav`. Not a solution as it currently stands. I think I may have to use js to fix this.

Comment: You never mentioned in the problem above that the link has to be clickable. Original problem was to overflow-x vs overflow-y. Let me update jsfiddle to make links clickable.

Comment: dude... it's a link.

Comment: I've already tried that, and advanced on it so the edges still appear to match up: https://jsfiddle.net/6xhtdpuu/ - it feels way too hacky though and not like a good solution for a production site. i'm going to use javascript to position the sub-nav I think.

Comment: You will face this issue as the scroll bar is applied to parent and will always be outside the child's body. Why you wanted to use nav bar in such way.